# Jquery Mobile white area when changing orientation

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, sencha-touch, orientation, extjs

I've developed a jquery mobile mobile web app & ive loaded it to a android web view.
The problem is when I change orientation, it re-sizes the window contents after showing a white area.
It happens for both width and height.

The duration of the white area can vary with the components in the page.

I've

```
<div data-role="page" style="min-width:100%;height:100%">
```

and overidden onConfigurationChanged in android activity.

Any help would be i=highly appreciated.
I have tried Sencha 1.1.0 and it gives the same issue.

Any help would be highly appreciated as I've been stuck on this for almost a week.

Comment: Last time I also have the same problem as you,  but after I change the body background color to match my div color and it works now

Comment: Hi thnx a lot.But even though you have added it, do you see the webview content expand to width after the orientation has changed.     How does facebook & linked in mobile apps change orientation smoothly?

Comment: Maybe they use JavaScript to determine the current width and height and auto Shuster it

Comment: Can we layout the width & height before the orientation completes?

Comment: @xDragonZ thanks a lot.I modified my css according to that link.It is a lot better now.The re-layout when changing orientation is barely visible.But nevertheless not smooth as Linkedin app.Facebook app also resizes after the orientation happens.

Comment: Glad to hear that you got it working, don't forget share your solutions :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest setting the body background, Example

- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_body_background.asp

To my understanding this is just displaying the body background